# Mysql Update Query Not worked

Tags: mysql

```
UPDATE `tbl_shift_details`  
SET EndTime  = '10:00:00' EndDate = '2016-10-15',
    EndBillNo = '50',`TempColl` = (Val(TempColl) + '500') 
WHERE `OperatorId` =  '3' AND machineId = '026'
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

This query not working for me,Because of `TempColl` field of same table used inside the query for select the previous value.
Kindly help in this regard

Comment: What datatype has `TempColl`?

Comment: What is `Val()`? Just use `TempColl = TempColl + 500`

Comment: Hi rbr94 and Paul Spiegel, it is my mistake,"TempColl" field is  already a numeric field ,Thank you so much for help me.

Comment: Even if it's not numeric, `+` will automatically convert strings to numbers in MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss a `,` here:

```
SET EndTime  = '10:00:00' EndDate = '2016-10-15',
```

It should look like this:

```
SET EndTime  = '10:00:00', EndDate = '2016-10-15',
```

An for your usage of `TempColl`. It should work like this, if the column is numeric:

```
TempColl = TempColl + 500
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your reply,It is worked.Avoided Val also

Comment: @GirishKumarG You're welcome. Mark the answer as accepted if this is the case